# data bridge between Java and Python daemons

Tags: java, python, database, distributed-computing, in-memory-database

I have two background processes running on linux machine. One is Java and second one is in Python. What would be most efficient way to **exchange data** between these two apps ? I am talking about text / images data **below < 10Mb approx each 5 minutes** (not streamed). Due high cost of refactoring we cannot migrate fully to Python (or Java).

Natural choice is filesystem or local networking but what about in memory database (sqllite/redis/...) ? *Filesystem handling or network handling is sometimes painfull i guess.*

**Do you think that in-memory-DB would be good option for such task ?** Jython is not option there as not all Python libraries are compatible...

Environment : ubuntu server 12.04 64bit, Python 2.7, Java 7

Comment: I would take a look at ZeroMQ. It is not painful at all and comes in both Python and Java flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to transfer the data would be a local TCP connection and stream the data with a common protocol.  [Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is one way to define your protocol across language platforms.  An in memory database would add a whole new component and unnecessary complexity to your system.

Answer (score 2):

[Unix domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) would be the fastest since it won't use the disk and it doesn't have unnecessary overhead like TCP.

Comment: Java cannot create or access Unix Domain Sockets without using a 3rd party (native) library - that makes things a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the relatively low volume of data you need, I would say the easiest way would be to use a TCP socket to communicate between the two processes. The data speed on the loopback interface is more than enough for your needs.